# How to make a Java program that takes two types of arguments?

Tags: java

so I want to have my program able to take two arguments: the first one is a text file path and the second one is an integer represents how many lines I want to see.

Right now, my code can work with the text file path argument but I can't get to the second method I made for the integer argument.

For example, I try to run my program like this:

> run Read test.txt 3

And it prints everything in the text file instead of 3 lines which I want it to be.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Read{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String in = new String(args[0]);
    String input = in;
    if (Character.isDigit(in.charAt(in.length() - 1))){
      hasNumInput(input);
    }else onlyStrInput(input);
  }

  public static void onlyStrInput(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    String input = "";
    while (inFile.hasNext()){
      input = inFile.next();
      if (!map.containsKey(input)) map.put(input,1);
      else map.put(input, map.get(input) + 1);
    }

    int index = 1;
    while (!map.isEmpty()) {
      int max = 0;
      String maxP = "";
      for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> stringIntegerEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) stringIntegerEntry;
        String key = (String) entry.getKey();
        Integer value = (Integer) entry.getValue();
        //if equals, alphabetically
        if (value == max) {
          if (maxP.compareTo(key) > 0) {
            max = value;
            maxP = key;
          }
        }
        if (value > max) {
          max = value;
          maxP = key;
        }
      }
      System.out.println(index++ + ". " + maxP + " = " + map.get(maxP));
      //pop out the max
      map.remove(maxP);
    }
  }

  public static void hasNumInput(String in) throws FileNotFoundException{
      int indexSpace = in.indexOf(" ");
      String strNum = in.substring(indexSpace + 1,in.length());
      int num = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
      String filename = in.substring(0,indexSpace);

      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
      HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
      String input = "";
      while (inFile.hasNext()){
        input = inFile.next();
        if (!map.containsKey(input)) map.put(input,1);
        else map.put(input, map.get(input) + 1);
      }

      int index = 1;
      while (!map.isEmpty() && num > 0) {
        int max = 0;
        String maxP = "";
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> stringIntegerEntry : map.entrySet()) {
          Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) stringIntegerEntry;
          String key = (String) entry.getKey();
          Integer value = (Integer) entry.getValue();
          //if equals, alphabetically
          if (value == max) {
            if (maxP.compareTo(key) > 0) {
              max = value;
              maxP = key;
            }
          }
          if (value > max) {
            max = value;
            maxP = key;
          }
        }
        System.out.println(index++ + ". " + maxP + " = " + map.get(maxP));
        //pop out the max
        map.remove(maxP);
        num--;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[] args` does not pass everything in `args[0]`, instead you must check the array length and then act accordingly. Your `hasNumInput` method should take an `int` argument (and the current `String`). Something like,

```
public static void hasNumInput(String in, int num) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(in);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Then your `main` might look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (args.length > 1) {
        hasNumInput(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    } else {
        onlyStrInput(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it makes so much sense to me!

Answer (score 1):

`args` is an array. As you already know, the first argument is the first element of the array, referred to using `args[0]` so logically, the second command line argument would be referred to using `args[1]` and so on.

```
public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("String = " + args[0]);
    System.out.println("int = " + args[1]);
  }
}
```

The `args` array is of type String, so if you want an int, you have to make sure to cast it using `Integer.valueOf(args[1]);`